# Ideally BHT could provide a lifesaving treatment

Tags: word-usage

Is the use of "could" in the phrase "Ideally BHT could provide a lifesaving treatment" emphasize a possibility? Can it be rewritten as "Ideally BHT **can** provide a lifesaving treatment"?

> Transplanting a head and brain is perhaps the final frontier of organ transplantation. The goal of body-to-head transplantation (BHT) is to sustain the life of individuals who suffer from terminal disease, but whose head and brain are healthy. **Ideally BHT could provide a lifesaving treatment** for several conditions where none currently exists.
> Source:  PMC  US National Library of Medicine
> National Institutes of Health
> [Surgical, ethical, and psychosocial considerations in human head transplantation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5490488/)

Comment: *Ideally, I **can** help* and *Ideally, I **could** help* both sound "odd" to me, because "ideally" implies that whatever follows is a ***hypothetical*** (future or "alternative present") situation. I'd go for *Ideally, I **will / would be able to** help*.

Answer (score 2):

No, because this surgical procedure does not exist, so it *can't* provide anything at the moment. *If* surgeons were able to do this, it *could* provide lifesaving treatment. This describes a hypothetical situation.